# Yiic not recognized as command in windows

Tags: windows, yii

this question might seems to have been asked before, but I think I'm encountering something else. I installed xampp and supposedly, `Yii framework`. When I tried to create a web app using yiic command I got :

> yiic is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

According to a question previously asked on stackoverflow, this is caused by the Path environment variable not configured correctly, which I did as I was advised, like in the image below, If I'm wrong, I clearly I didn't know where and you guys might do. Please help
[image]

Comment: another one!!!!! Where did you install yii?

Comment: I suggest you go and have a look at [this page](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/408/install-update-and-use-yii-with-wamp-server/)

Comment: I am using xampp, not wampp. Does this mean I actually had to install Yii in the www folder in C:\xampp\php instead of the htdocs folder?

Comment: No, it means wherever you installed it, you need to add the correct path.

Comment: I have added the path to yii folder, right below the path to php folder as in the image. Is there another path I have to specifiy?

Comment: ok, so then from CMDline can you run `c:\xampp\htdocs\yiiframework\yiic`

Comment: still not working :( I ran yiic in the yii folder and still have the same problem. I'm starting to think maybe I missed a file or two. Can you please check [this](https://imgur.com/a/ulJy9) out?

Comment: same error? then please do me a favour. goto cmd.exe and do `cd\` then do `dir /S yiic*` and send the path where it finds the yiic executable.

Comment: It says file not found. So I suppose this mean I am missing yiic executable. I just ran through the installing process again( I install through cmd with composer) and still get stuck :(

Comment: first do `dir /S yiic` and then `dir /S yiic.*` and `dir /S yiic*` to see if it finds anything

Comment: third command is a hit, which pointed to yii.captcha, I don't think this is what I need. I also tried to run cmd from that directory but in vain. I also tried to add that directory to path variable but still nothing came up

Comment: So that ia the problem. Yiic does not exist

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded and unzipped yii in wamp www in folder yii.  There was no framework folder in the distribution but instructions said to execute yiic from the framework folder.  I search the distribution and there is no yiic, or framework.